# XSLT and the for-each loop

Tags: xslt

I am using the XML file here

http://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xml

And I have written this code

```
  <xsl:for-each select="registry/record">
```

However it never finds anything because of this line in the XML

```
<registry xmlns="http://www.iana.org/assignments" id="service-names-port-numbers">
```

If I change that to

```
<registry>
```

It works, however I cannot change the XML, I must change the XSLT.  What can I do to make it work?  I just need to find those records.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XSLT and XPath are namespace-aware. Unfortunately they don't have any notation for setting a default namespace for the path, so you have to use an explicit prefix bound to the namespace.

If you aren't familiar with XML Namespaces, do review them. They're important.

Taking your specific example, here's a simplified version of the start of the SNTP document

```
<registry xmlns="http://www.iana.org/assignments" id="service-names-port-numbers">
  <title>Service Name and Transport Protocol Port Number Registry</title>
  <category>Service Names and Transport Protocol Port Numbers</category>
  <updated>2014-02-06</updated>
  <xref type="rfc" data="rfc6335"/>
  <expert> ... names of experts ... </expert>
  <note> ... usage notes ... </note>
  <record>
    <protocol>tcp</protocol>
    <xref type="person" data="Jon_Postel"/>
    <description>Reserved</description>
    <number>0</number>
  </record>
</registry>
```

The `xmlns="http://www.iana.org/assignments"` is a default namespace binding. All elements in this document will be in that namespace unless they have a prefix bound to another namespace or another `xmlns=` is used to change the default for them and their children.

Your XPaths and Match Expressions *MUST* reference this namespace, or they won't work.

Change

```
 <xsl:for-each select="registry/record">
```

to

```
 <xsl:for-each select="assignments:registry/assignments:record"
   xmlns:assignments="http://www.iana.org/assignments">
```

(You can use a shorter prefix than `assignments`; I'm just trying to make this as clear as possible. You can also bind the prefix higher in your XSLT document -- typically, on the `<xsl:stylesheet>` element -- so it's available throughout the stylesheet rather than just in this one place.)

This will work, assuming the rest of your code is correct.

Also: In general, `<xsl:for-each>` tends to be overused. In general, unless this is a place where you really do need to do different processing than anywhere else in the stylesheet, you should instead be using `<xsl:apply-templates>` so the normal template-matching rules can apply. Otherwise you're making the stylesheet hard to extend and maintain. XSL is a rule-matching, nonprocedural language; learn to use it that way.

Comment: This does not work for me either.  Where is the namespace assignments in that XML?

Comment: I do this in the templates:

<xsl:template match="/">

Comment: Namespace assignments in that xml: `xmlns="http://www.iana.org/assignments"` binds the default namespace. You need to match it.

You didn't show us `<record>`, so I'm assuming it's using the same default namespace. It may not, if there's another `xmlns=` on it. Show us a more complete input sample.

Comment: You're trying to write the solution as a single template matching at the root. As I say, that is _usually_ not the best answer; you're forcing XSLT into a procedural style rather than taking advantage of its design as a rule-based language. You can make it work, but you're going to work harder to write and maintain stylesheets in this style.

Comment: I cannot add my XSLT, it won't let me.  I have this in there:

xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"

Comment: record is in that link at the start of my question

Comment: `xmlns:xsl=...` That's correct, that's what makes the xsl: prefix in your stylesheet be interpreted as indicating that those elements belong to the XSLT language. It has nothing to do with the point I'm making about having to write namespace-aware XPaths if you want them to match namespaced elements in the input document.

Comment: Checked the source doc. Clarified my answer. It remains correct.

Comment: Yeah, you're right.  I was getting things mixed up.  Thanks a lot.